# Read only one line of Integers from a file

Tags: java, int, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a file which contains integers. The file has 40 lines, each having 80 integers. However when I run the following code, I get 40 lines and 3200 integers in each line (it reads the entire file for each line). How can I fix this.

```
    while(input.hasNextLine()){
        ++rows;
        Scanner colReader = new Scanner(input.nextLine());
        while(colReader.hasNextInt()){
            ++columns;
            colReader.nextInt();
        }
        colReader.close();
   }
```

Comment: You need to reset the columns for each line.  Otherwise you increment  columns up to 3200.

Comment: Thank you, that is what was missing. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simplify your code somewhat.  You can keep on reading integers one by one.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("f:/numbs.txt"));
while (input.hasNextInt()) {
       int v = input.nextInt();
       System.out.println(v);
}
```

Comment: I want the number of rows and columns too.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are duplicated the loop, if you want to read a file, you can do the next

```
BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("")));
        int line;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ( (line =bufferReader.read()) != 0 ) {
           // Do something
        }
```

Comment: You only need to cast the object, example Integer.parseInt(line);

Comment: That's not a cast, it's a conversion from String to int.  And it isn't necessary since Scanner does it for you.

Comment: Bufferreader permits the same,  you only need to do the next                                                              while ( (line =bufferReader.read()) != 0 ) {